# See all shared items in Google Drive

Tags: google-drive

In Dropbox there is a place you can see all the shared items in your account (i.e., all the items you have granted others access to).

Is there a similar feature in Google Drive?

I'm not only trying to find items that are shared with other "named people", but also documents that are shared on a "anyone with link can view / edit" or "public on the internet" basis.

Franck's [answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/52095) seemed to work back in 2013, but Google Drive's interface has changed quite a bit since, and I'm struggling to be able to perform the same task with the new interface. I wonder if anyone knows how to do it in the new interface.

Comment: I've got a Google Script that'll write this to a Google Sheet. It's at https://gist.github.com/woodwardtw/22a199ecca73ff15a0eb

Comment: Thanks @TomWoodward is there a way to get that script to work on the whole of google drive, rather than a particular folder ?

Comment: I Guess what you are looking for is this Add-on :
https://gsuite.google.com/marketplace/app/drive_manager/1049726953004

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Search for `to:` to retrieve all documents shared with someone. You can also search by visibility:

[image]

For more information, see [Search your Google Drive](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2375114?hl=en).

Comment: Thanks Franck im trying to do another audit at the moment, but google drive have changed their search drop down, in the new drop down is there a way to filter by visibility like there was in the dropdown that you screenshoted above ?

Comment: @sam sorry, no clue, I don't use Google Drive much, their user interface hurts my eyes.

Comment: The `to:` operator worked well for me. To remove access, I also found it useful to search for `to:person@domain.com -owner:person@domain.com` as I can't otherwise revoke access from all the files.

Comment: This didn't work for me - maybe because it was a folder and not a file?

Comment: As of 2023 there doesn't seem to be a built-in way to do this from the web UI. It's possible via the Google Drive API, and there's a web-based API Explorer that returns JSON. To get all files that are shared as "Anyone with link", go to v3's reference page for Files: list, click on the "Try it" button and set `corpora` to `user`, and `q` to `visibility = 'anyoneWithLink'`. Here's a [direct link](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list?apix_params=%7B%22corpora%22%3A%22user%22%2C%22q%22%3A%22visibility%20%3D%20%27anyoneWithLink%27%22%7D)

Comment: You have to confirm: "Google APIs Explorer wants to access your Google Account" with "See, edit, create and delete all of your Google Drive files

See and download all your Google Drive files

View the photos, videos and albums in your Google Photos

View and manage metadata of files in your Google Drive

See, create and delete its own configuration data in your Google Drive

See information about your Google Drive files

See, edit, create and delete only the specific Google Drive files that you use with this app" – But since it's a Google product, I hope it is safe!

Comment: 10 years later ... and Google has not implemented a simple way to get files **shared with others**. Disappointing.

Answer (score 17):

As of 2017, Google Drive does not have this feature built in.  Limited functionality can be achieved using [advanced search](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2375114), however, that can be complicated, and still does not fully answer your question.

Instead, you can use [WhoHasAccess.com](https://www.whohasaccess.com/).  The interface is user-based, which means that instead of listing directly the files that are shared, it will list the people that the files are shared with.  If you absolutely need a file by file based interface, this might not be the solution for you, but there's a lot of potential if you can work around that.

To start, go to [WhoHasAccess.com](https://www.whohasaccess.com/), and click <kbd>Scan my Google Drive now</kbd>.

[image: WhoHasAccess.com]

Next, you'll need to give WhoHasAccess.com permission to view and manage your Google Drive files. Don't worry - after the scan is completed, they'll delete the collected data within 24 hours.

[image: Grant Access]

Next, you'll have to wait a few minutes, depending on how much stuff you keep in your drive.  When the scan is finished, you'll see a page like the one below, and be able to manage who has access to what.

[image]

---

### If That's Not Good Enough

A slightly more complicated method is available if you're more tech savvy, and/or need the information presented differently.  @Tom Woodward left a comment above that you can run [his Google Script](https://gist.github.com/woodwardtw/22a199ecca73ff15a0eb), which will output a csv (Comma Separated Value) file, which is open-able in Excel.

Comment: To be honest, I would rather look all my files one by one than giving all kind of access permissions (read,write,delete for all files) to third party apps.

Comment: Is it safe to give access to this extension?

Comment: Whether it's safe to give access is something you'll have to decide for yourself, but their [privacy policy](https://www.whohasaccess.com/privacy) says that they don't share any of the information.  Personally, that's good enough for me since they seem legit, but if you have super sensitive information on your Google Drive, that might not be the option for you.

Comment: THIS SITE ROCKS.  Why isn't this a built in feature of Google?   and yes, the site obviously needs full permissions but it is very clear about what it's using,and deletes all data & permissions within 24 hours, unless you click the "forget me now" (or whatever) button at the bottom..... I was **shocked** to see all the crap I had shared with random people over the last 15 years.  (Also found a bunch of cool stuff of mine, hidden away in subfolders, that I'd forgotten about!)

Comment: @emrecan totally agree!  The permissions are ridiculous - just blanket all access and unnecessary: access should only be read-only. Even better - access could be even more finer granularity: allow listing of files any folders, allow reading of sharing information, but not the _contents_ of the files themselves. I've raised such coarse granularity issues with Google here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/204692011?pli=1

Comment: Never trust anyone with sensitive data. They might be treating it right, but what if a hacker got access to their system and always copies each incoming file. Good luck with your sensitive data spreading across the internet.

Answer (score 12):

I have modified the code provided by Tom Woodward in the comments. You can see it over here: https://gist.github.com/danjargold/c6542e68fe3a3b46eeb0172f914641bc

Tom's original code only scanned a single folder and one level down of subfolders. With my modification, it will scan your whole drive irrespective of the number of folders within folders you have. Take note that it will miss any loose files in your top/home folder. Another improvement I made was to only list files that are not PRIVATE.

To you use, simply:

1. Create a new google sheet
2. Select Tools -> Script Editor
3. Copy the code from https://gist.github.com/danjargold/c6542e68fe3a3b46eeb0172f914641bc
4. Save and run (click the play button)

Feedback is always appreciated :)

Comment: Nice. What is missing in this approach: it's the capacity to handle big volume of files. It stops after 5-6 minutes otherwise.

Comment: Still works! +1

Comment: Note in 2023 you go to "Tools > Apps Scripts" which opens a new tab/window. Paste the code. click "save" at the top, then "run"

Answer (score 8):

As of May 2018 there is still no way to view this information via the Google Drive interface, other than going through the files individually. In addition, when using the Google Drive API in the standard way and searching for files that are public there is a bug which leads to inaccurate results (https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/72970146).

One way to get the information you need is to use Filewatch (https://filewatch.rekatsu.com), a free tool I made which scans your Google Drive and displays all of the files which are publicly available (shared with anyone on the web or anyone with the link). It scans all files which you have permission to share, including files you don’t own and files in team drives you have access to.

Go to Filewatch (https://filewatch.rekatsu.com), and click on ‘Connect service’ under Google Drive.

[image: Filewatch]

You’ll need to give permission for Filewatch to scan your files. Filewatch has been verified by Google, requests the minimum permissions necessary and no information about your files leaves your computer. You can also revoke the permissions at any time by clicking ‘Disconnect service’.

[image: Filewatch permissions]

Start the scan by clicking the ‘Find now’ button. Filewatch will scan your files and display the results to you. It only takes a few seconds. You’ll be able to see how many files were scanned and a list of the files which are publicly available. You can then review them and change the sharing settings if necessary.

[image: Filewatch results]

Comment: for some reason, it only found 3 public files, but WhoHasAccess.com found about 20 (owned by me, not just those I have access to)

Comment: @LogicDaemon Thanks for trying Filewatch. I've done some testing and everything seems to be working as expected.Could I ask, when you say that WhoHasAccess.com found about 20, does that mean that it found 20 files in total or 20 files that are public (Public on the web or Anyone with the link)?

Comment: 20 public for everyone. 9 more with the link. Here are screenshots: https://photos.app.goo.gl/8GHmyfLve4hZ6NgE8 (yes, I'm certain account is the same, PM me somewhere if I can help with diagnostics)

Comment: @LogicDaemon Thanks so much for the offer to help diagnosing the issue. If the offer is still open it's probably easiest if you email me at contact@filewatch.net. There's a couple of things we can check.

Comment: This is nice but it shows all the files shared with me. I was looking only for my owned files and not trashed. Because I have thousands of files shared with me. It would be very nice if if has those options which are implementable, because I had to do a script to find them in Java (in case that script helps anybody here it is: https://github.com/Ortega-Dan/javaGdriveReader)

Answer (score 5):

Two methods that are available (neither is ideal imo) is to:

1. in google drive, switch to the listing view (instead of grid view). If an item is shared, there should be a small "two head" icon next to the name. If a folder is shared, there should be a "head" icon on the folder.
2. Download / install the google drive sync application for your computer and open the resulting folder. Again, in detail view, you can add a column (right click on the header/title row) called "shared".

I'm not sure if these work for all combinations (non-shared folder containing shared file, link share vs. full share) but it does help. Really hoping Google will figure this out soon as this keeps our professional use to a minimum and using OneDrive instead.

Comment: nice, didn't know about the additional column.

Comment: the 2. method does not work for "anyone with a link" sharing - the "Shared" column lists "No" in this case

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a full python program to query the Google Drive API and audit Drive for sharing and many other file properties. It will dump "interesting" files and all folders to csv.

The CSVs display full folder information, including total numbers of all children and total size of all children in the directories. This is useful if you're near drive quota limit, or if you don't like that GoogleDriveUploader scans through 100k files every time your computer starts up. I'll hopefully augment it to enable users to programatically remove sharing on files.

I wrote this because I found that the gist didn't work well for huge numbers of files (I had in the 100Ks). I think there were also API limits, debugging the sheets API seemed to be difficult.

https://github.com/jsrozner/google_drive_auditer

Comment: In case it helps anybody. Here is a basic Java version that gets the job done securely, that is pretty much the QuickStart from Google Drive API official documentation and some minor adjustments. And it only uses pure Java and the Google Drive API official libraries. Nothing else. And the pom.xml file shows no more dependencies are used. And actual code (besides comments and imports) is less than 90 lines. https://github.com/Ortega-Dan/javaGdriveReader

Answer (score 2):

If you are a Workspace or GSuite customer:

- Go to https://admin.google.com/ac/reporting/audit/drive?new=true
- Filter by "visibility: public on the web".

There are of course several other criterias like the owner, previous visibility and beyond.

Comment: Neat!!! Exactly what we needed here! You can even create alerts and stuff. Thank you so much!