# In Google Drive how do I find everything I shared with other people?

Tags: google-drive, privacy

I accidentally shared some photos on Google Drive with the wrong recipient (Google account). Since not all the shared documents were in the same folder, what's the easiest way to go through them and remove sharing privileges?

Comment: This post includes two different questions, one in the title and another in the body. I think that the second deserves it's own post.

Comment: Also: [See all shared items in Google Drive](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/52093/354)

Answer (score 4):

Search for `to:` to retrieve all documents shared with someone. You can also search by visibility.

See Google Drive Help: [Find items in Google Drive](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2375114?hl=en)